# Is it possible that git status tells you everything is up to date when actually it is not?

Tags: git

Yesterday, I merged some branches that I worked on during the weekend into master. Then I deleted every branch except for master. All of these changes were done during the weekend so the local repository in my work computer was outdated. Today I came to work and ran `git status`, and it said

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

However I was 100% sure  my local repo at work was not up to date, because I made several changes. After running `git pull` It downloaded all my changes and everything worked fine.

My question is: Is it possible that under some circumstances `git status` can tell you you are up to date with remote when you are not? I am not sure if this is expected behavior or git just messed up.

Comment: Do a `git fetch` before `git status`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git status` does not check the actual remote repository. It tells you if you are up-to-date with respect to the local copy of the remote repository. Just remember that `origin` is a cached copy of the remote which resides on your computer, and not the remote repository itself.

You have to `git fetch` to update this local cache, after which `git status` will tell you if you are behind or not.

Comment: Use gitk or similar to see where "master" and "origin/master" are.  You can easily see that the values are cached from your last fetch/pull and not up to date.

Answer (score 3):

How does git know which branch to compare with exactly?

git does not do a diff with the actual remote repository. It keeps track of the diff by comparing your local branches to the corresponding *remote references* (`origin/master` for example). To get the correct (updated) git status, you need to `fetch` from the remote, which will update the remote references. You can do that by
`git fetch origin`

`git status` will then give you the correct diff.

When you did a `git pull`, what you actually did is a fetch followed by a merge, which resulted in your local branch being brought up to date with the remote master. If you want, you can do just a `git fetch` and then git will tell you how many commits your local master is behind the remote one.

So you should always fetch from the remote before:

1. creating a feature branch
2. pushing to remote
3. wanting to compare between local and remote branches